# Show only the first 5 characters in select SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I would like to know if it is possible to show only the 5 first characters.

I've tried using **LEFT** but couldn't.
What I want is that when performing the query only the first 5 characters appear.
EX:
How is it done today:

> 380.902349

How I wanted it to be:

> 380.90

Can you help me.

Comment: `380.90` is six characters.  perhaps you may mean, _I want to limit the precision to two decimals_

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?

Answer (score 2):

Cast *after* the mathematical calculation.  And, use the size of the decimal you want.  Something like this:

```
CAST(AVG(md-duration * 1.0) / 1000 as DECIMAL(10, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL [FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format) function its take 2 parameters first value and second how much digit you want after decimal point.